# deleting replies on post previews on the homepage

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

Does anyone know how I can remove the text that says how many Replies there are underneath each post preview on my homepage? I would prefer to see just the title and the date.

This is something I expected to find in the lower portion of the code in the content.php file, but I don't see anything there that I can remove which will do the trick.

Am I missing something?

Thanks so so much to anyone who can reply

my site is at: dev.travelwithcastle.com
it is a Wordpress child theme, Twentytwelve

Kelly

I am including the code I have in content.php as well here:

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content. Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br><?php the_date(); ?>
            </h1>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <div class="comments-link">
                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comments-link -->
            <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() ) : // Display Excerpts for Search and Homepage ?>

        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
                <div class="author-info">
                    <div class="author-avatar">
                        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                    <div class="author-description">
                        <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                        <div class="author-link">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                                <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .author-link -->
                    </div><!-- .author-description -->
                </div><!-- .author-info -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

.entry-header .comments-link {
visibility: hidden;
}

you may want to change the height.